Beginner python tensorflow/keras woes... packages not recognized
I am new to python programming and as a means of learning am taking on some fun AI challenges. Not ashamed to admit I've let GPT help me by asking it to assemble some starter code that I can dissect, learn from, and then add to once I understand the basics.
In trying to put together a simple convolutional neural network that will do image recognition, the following imports are suggested:
import os
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequentialpip
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

unfortunately all of the tensorflow.keras. imports are failing in Visual Studio Code with a "could not be resolved" error.
What I have tried:
Research says that tensorflow, or at least the keras parts, aren't supported in Python 3.12, which I had selected as my Python interpreter. To remedy this, I followed the recommendation to install Python 3.10, verified it was a good install.
Then I started a virtual environment 'env' with Python3.10, installed tensorflow and all the other packages with pip for this environment. I had no errors installing the packages and my command prompt is showing that I'm indeed in my virtual environment.
I've used pip show and verified that all the packages, including tensorflow, are installed.
I've also been googling and reading about tensorflow and trying to find examples of code on other sites that is close to what I'm trying to accomplish, but I'm not having a lot of luck there. Being a beginner with both Python and tensorflow, I'm sure there's something basic I'm missing about why these imports are failing.
Having all this failing, I noticed that Keras itself is an installable package so I tried just importing from Keras. But that also is not found.

have you actually run the code? vscode messages can be false positives or just plain incorrect.

Wow, you nailed it, thank you. I'm a C# programmer who usually works in Visual Studio and would have never even tried to run code that displayed errors. It's just not done :-). Never imagined that vscode would behave this way, but I'm not going to complain. The code works perfectly! This could be tricky in the future, as i have run into learning cases where I really needed to import a package/library and had forgotten.
